# Disable the default active when hover

Tags: css

Here is example for my code

```
<style>
.hover:hover,.active{color:red}
</style>
<li class="hover active">Home</li>
<li class="hover">blog</li>
<li class="hover">about</li>
<li class="hover">port</li>
<li class="hover">contact</li>
```

If you mouse over on blog, there will be two red words
i am trying to find a way to disable "home" when you mouse over any other word
and then it back red if you moved the mouse away
After long search with google, i finnally found javascript code
And tried to modify it to work, but no luck

Comment: So Home should always be red unless another list item is being hovered over, in which case that item should be red?

Comment: @j08691 thankyou very much for your reply, Yes, this is exactly what i am trying to do, i want home to be always red, unless another list item is being hovered

Comment: Sorry for my english, I wish if an moderator could modifiy the post and make it better so other people can get helpled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution, that will work so long as you have a wrapper element for there `li`'s, which you should.

```html
<style>
  .menu:hover .active {
    color: black;
    /*reset the color to the default*/
    /*you could also use color: inherit*/
  }
  .hover:hover,
  .active,
  .menu:hover .active:hover {
    color:red
  }
</style>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="hover active">Home</li>
    <li class="hover">blog</li>
    <li class="hover">about</li>
    <li class="hover">port</li>
    <li class="hover">contact</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I am noticing right off is the improper markup
there is no

that may not have anything to do with it.

```
<style>
.hover:hover,.active{color:red}
</style>
<ul>
    <li class="hover active">Home</li>
    <li class="hover">blog</li>
    <li class="hover">about</li>
    <li class="hover">port</li>
    <li class="hover">contact</li>
</ul>
```

not exactly sure what you are trying to do

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/tfqw93tk/

maybe paste the js code you found and see if we can figure out your issue